# Only one user accessible spring security

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, spring-security

Here is my problem - I'm using Spring Security for authorization users, but I can login only to one user (test). Another users which I'm creating (through website or manually in db not work). db is MySQL , spring security 3.2.6.RELEASE.

security-context.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd


http://www.springframework.org/schema/security

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/"
        default-target-url="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/error"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" /> <!-- określamy przekierowanie po wylogowaniu -->
    <!-- <csrf />   włączamy zabezpieczenie przed csrf -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/addnew" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
                users-by-username-query="SELECT login, pass, mail FROM user WHERE login =?"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT login, role FROM roles WHERE login =?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="1234" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

chunk of .jsp code responsible of login:

```
<c:set var="sign">
    <c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />
</c:set>
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar right" action="${sign}" method="POST">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"
                                    placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="action">Sign In</button>
                        </form>
```

Db is connected correctly, because when I'm changing password manually in db for 'test' user, I need to login with neew password. This is User class, but I don't think it's relevant:

```
package com.codedig.app;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity //deklaruje, ze mamy do czynienia z encja
public class User {
    //niezalenize czy istnieja gettery/settery (akcesory) wszystkie wlasnosci obiektu sa zapisywane do bd

    @Id //deklaruje klucz wg. którego rozrozniamy encje
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;
    @Column(name = "pass")
    private String pass;
    @Column(name = "mail")
    private String mail;    

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(int id, String login, String pass, String mail) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.login = login;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

}
```

Edit: authorities-by-username-query might look a bit messy, but I had problem with 3>2 index (if I recall correctly - if you know how proper query should look like - don't hesitate to point out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working answer, but I think point into right direction - I forgot about 'enabled' field. After adding it into db and mapping it at User class it is still not working (suprisingly), but the problem probably is, that I'm using hibernate to handle another db at this project. I'm going to change my project to be full hibernate-using, this should fix it.

Comment: Finally - I do not know what was the problem with using JDBC, but with Hibernate connecting to user db it is all working good.

Comment: Hi, I have a same problem like you. But I used Spring Boot and here is my question link. Can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994418/spring-boot-security-allows-only-one-usertest1-login

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that every user has at least one role. If a user has no role, Spring Security will deny a login.

Comment: I'm sure they have roles, here is db.user screen : http://gyazo.com/35bf6db426e0459dfc1d0100c750b7f0
db.roles: http://gyazo.com/620e8f327a17cd4249d51011c990cc2a

Comment: What are the contents of the role table?

Comment: And also post the error messages, if you have them in the logfile.

Comment: I updated with role table, and there is no error. It is pointing me to /error page, like I would try to login with random username and password. I restarted db and tomcat couple times.