# spring boot security allows only one user(test1) to login

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I coded login function with spring boot security.

Here is configureGlobal method in class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
 @Autowired
 private DataSource dataSource;

 @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery(
                "select user_id, user_nm, password, enabled from user_table where user_id=?"
        ).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                "select user_id, authority from user_roles_table where user_id=?"
        );

    }
```

And it's not working except only one user which is test1.

Others can't login and always redirect to here.

```
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Invalid username and password.
</div>
```

What is the problem? Is this related with Hibernate or JDBC?

Comment: If it would be a JDBC problem, then no user could login. Hibernate is not involved here. Have all users at least one role?

Comment: yes, all users have one role like ADMIN, USER...

Comment: So what is different between user test1 and the others?

Comment: Your `usersByUsernameQuery` is wrong... It should return 3 columns (username, password, enabled) and yours is returning 4 columns... So that it works for a user is mere luck.

Comment: yes, it was wrong query problem. thank you. Anyway, is there any way to select other columns like user_id,user_nm,password,enable, etc......?